# Есть ли возможность прописать условие внутри атрибута элемента?

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor

Например, есть такой элемент:

```
<div class="points"></div>
```

Я бы хотел сделать что-то типа этого:

```
<div class="points" style="background-color: @{if (movie.Points < 40) return red @*И другие условия*@}"><div/>
```

Но я нашел лишь такой способ:

```
@if(movie.Points < 40)
{
    <div class="points" style="background-color: red"></div>
}
else if(movie.Points > 40 && movie.Points < 70)
{
    <div class="points" style="background-color: yellow"></div>
}
```

Выглядит не совсем эстетично, нужно каждый раз переписывать весь div. Есть ли какой-то способ сделать это  красивее?

Comment: [Здесь](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/aspnet/core/mvc/views/razor?view=aspnetcore-3.1) смотрели?

Comment: Смотрел, но ничего подходящего не нашел

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так:

```
@{
    string color = null;
    if (movie.Points < 40)
    {
        color = "red";
    }
    else if (movie.Points > 40 && movie.Points < 70)
    {
        color = "yellow";
    }
}

<div class="points" style="background-color: @color"></div>
```

Не уверен, что это сильно красивее. Однако, если в блоке кода будут задаваться множество разных локальных переменных, а потом использоваться в разметке, то это уже будет смотреться лучше.

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте такой подход

```
<div style="@(true ? "display:block" : "display:none")"></div>
```

display:block - блочный элемент
display:none - скрывает элемент

в вашем случае:

```
<div style="@(movie.Points < 40 ? "background-color:red" 
             : movie.Points > 40 && movie.Points < 70 ? 
             "background-color:yellow" : "")"></div>
```

Comment: `display:none` скрывает элемент, а не удаляет из документа.

Comment: Поправил, действительно скрывает.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ! Такой подход имеет место быть, но мне он кажется не совсем читаемым